# Python: Error 34: Integer overflow (beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I have to handle very big integers in my program, but I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]", line n, in <module>
    number = int(numbers[0]*(10**numbers[1]))
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

for `number = int(n)`when I entered 8e10000000 as n.

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to handle numbers quite that large? `8e10000000` is an enormous number

Comment: The code you give (`number = int(8e10000000)`) is different from the one that appears in the traceback (`number = int(numbers[0]*(10**numbers[1]))`, and they are very different, as the first one involves a float, while the second one only uses integers. Please clarify your question.

Comment: This **isn't integer overflow**, which doesn't happen in Python. The problem occurs **before** `int` can be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`8e10000000` is very large number, and Python it represents as a float.
CPython usually store this float in 64-bit size, which is too small for such a big number.

For such large numbers is safe to use `Decimal` module:

```
import sys
from decimal import Decimal

print('max size = ', sys.maxsize)
number = Decimal("8e10000000")
print(number)
```

Outputs:

```
max size =  9223372036854775807
8E+10000000
```

The number 9223372036854775807 is exactly 2^63 - 1.

Comment: In Python 3, there is **no** maximum integer. `sys.maxsize` returns " an integer giving the maximum value a variable of type Py_ssize_t can take. It’s usually 2* *31 - 1 on a 32-bit platform and 2**63 - 1 on a 64-bit platform.", this is completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, you have right. That's Python2. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The number `8e10000000` is not an integer, it is a floating point number to Python. Any number using the `e` notation is treated as a float. Python uses (usually) a 64-bit float format, and that cannot hold such a large number.

So the problem is not the integer, it is the float you start with. The error is not at the line `number = int(n)`, it is at the line `n = 8e10000000` or whatever equivalent you used.

You can avoid that error by using

```
n = 8 * 10**10000000
```

This results in an integer. But be careful--that takes a lot of time and memory to build the integer in RAM. (My system took 19 seconds to execute that one command.) And if you try to print that value, the computer will take a *very long time* and a large amount of memory to build up the string value to be printed.

Finally, as others have pointed out, that statement that you claim does not match the error message. So it is possible that something else is going on. If you want closure from us, show an entire code snippet that shows that error.

Answer (score 0):

What you're running into is an issue where python is *Strongly Typed* but also *Dynamically  Typed*.  8e10000000 is actually of the python (and C) type `float` and is a valid value for a double precision floating point binary representation, whereas the maximum valid value for a python `int` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (found with `sys.maxint`).

So, python has a `decimal` library that has a class `decimal.Decimal` [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) that does arbitrary precision numbers.  It's not going to be as memory or speed efficient, but it bypasses the size-limit and precision issues that floating point numbers have, and are particularly when dealing with money.

The other option that you can consider if you are truly using inter values is to use `long(n)` to cast your variable to an arbitrarily large integer in python 2.5+ (in python 3.0+ `int` is a `long`) here's a link to the [PEP 237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) that talks about it.